# Virtualenv - workon command not found

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I followed these steps to set up virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip

$ sudo pip3 install virtualenv
$ sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper

$ mkdir ~/.virtualenvs

$ export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs

$ VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3'

$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

$ mkvirtualenv venv
$ virtualenv venv
```

So far it was working fine but I restarted the shell and then I tried `workon venv` and now it says: `command not found`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> So far it was working fine but **I restarted the shell**

The reason is because you restarted the shell.

If you want this to work with each shell, you'll need to add these to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After adding this, you'll want to `source ~/.bashrc` so the changes take effect. You'll find that you have access to `virtualenvwrapper` facilities in each new shell.

Comment: You may have to add this to `.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: It works but I have to do source ~/.bashrc each time I open a new terminal window or label

Comment: @JesusAlmaral-Hackaprende Did you read the comment right above yours?

Comment: Yes, what I had to do was instead of using ~/.bashrc I used ~/.zshrc, this is for Mac Big Sur

Comment: From many virtualenvwrapper stack overflow Q & A-s this is the correct answer. Tank you.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add commands

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file. So that whenever you start shell these commands are loaded automatically.

For the [reference](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file).