# Using python to open a new terminal and run a command in that terminal

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to optimise my workflow and so I want to issue a command from a python program that will open a terminal, switch to a specific directory and then run a command, in this case activate a virtual environment.

This question is similar to [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332703/open-terminal-run-command-python) However, I am not sure how to handle the call to the virtualenv.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['gnome-terminal', '--working-directory', '/home/jeff/projects', 'bash \"workon wagtail\" '])
```

What happens is that the new window get created in the correct directory but the *workon* does not get called

Working in the terminal, if I use

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/jeff/projects'  -- bash -ci "source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon ; exec bash;"
```

The command works, but the workon is performed before the terminal prompt appears

If I run

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/jeff/projects'  -- bash -ci "source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon wagtail; exec bash;"
```

the terminal does not enter the venv (wagtail). However the command

```
workon wagtail
```

is in the terminal history

Comment: The `~` won't be expanded unless you pass `shell=True` to `subprocess.run`.

Comment: @textux Thanks - you're right of course, but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: whats currently happening, do you get an error; does a window pop up; does it open but not in the right directory?

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge I've edited the question

Comment: You normally need `gnome-terminal -e bash ...` I think you are missing the `-e`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm making some progress the command
 gnome-terminal --working-directory /home/jeff/projects  -- bash -c "workon; exec bash" 
Is almost there, but gives error bash: workon command not found

Comment: Cool - have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611480/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. I don't think that's the problem. workon is fine if I call it from the command line, but not in a script. This works: gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/jeff/projects'  -- bash -ci "echo hello; exec bash;"
but  this doesn't:  gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/jeff/projects'  -- bash -ci "workon ; exec bash;"

Comment: When working at the command-line, `bash` is run as a login shell and sets up your environment using its startup files. When `bash` is run by `gnome-terminal` it doesn't do that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you. This works: gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/jeff/projects'  -- bash -ci "source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon ; exec bash;", but this does not: gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/jeff/projects'  -- bash -ci "source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon  wagtail; exec bash;". The command is run BEFORE the terminal prompt appears

Comment: Cool - you can add it as the answer and accept it and bag the points. Then everyone can see, in a nicely formatted way, how to do it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell But it doesn't work! This is the command I want. It runs the 'workon wagtail' before the terminal prompt appears and the venv is not invoked: gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/jeff/projects' -- bash -ci "source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon wagtail; exec bash;"

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your comment. Maybe you could click `edit` under your question and add your latest, greatest code in there where it is nicely formatted and easy for everyone to read rather than wading through the comments, please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Question updated!

Comment: I don't understand why you `exec bash`. That will **replace** the current `bash` process in which you have run `workon` with a new `bash` process in which you haven't. Why do you do that? You are already running a perfectly happy `bash` process, surely?

Comment: @MarkSetchell If I do not use exec bash then the new terminal disappears. I want a new terminal,wthere I want to run the workon command