# How to resolve workon:commnad not found for virtualenv?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have both python 2.7 and 3.8 and wanted to run virtualenv on 3.8. As the result of `which python3` was `/usr/local/bin/python3` I did `virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 virEnv` and then `source virEnv/bin/activate` to start the virtualenv. Now I switched to another terminal (on visual studio code) and ran `workon virEnv` and it gave `workon:command not found`. I searched for the solution on stackoverflow and found this thread [workon:command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611394/virtualenv-workon-command-not-found/34611480) and did

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/local/bin/python3'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

But the third line is resulting in

```
/usr/local/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly
```

I want to work on my virtualenv on any terminal by running `workon name`. Please help.

Comment: With this command `virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 virEnv`, You are using `virtualenv` here, not `virtualenvwrapper`. To make a separate environment using `virtualenvwrapper` you need to run `mkvirtualenv ENV_NAME` where ENV_NAME is env name you want to set to. Also, have you tried installing virtualenvwrapper with `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`?

Comment: Consider visiting MDN Django page where it covers [virtualenvwrapper setting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment#macOS_virtual_environment_setup)

Comment: @harryghgim Whenever I use pip3 I get `WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`

Comment: I'm not sure about that message, but [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3) might help